# How can I add 1 millisecond to a current timestamp in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to add 1 millisecond to all objects in my collection. I'm looking at created_date specifically. Such as this:

```
    {
  _id: 'd751b295-6597-4a0b-bd64-89b0fbaac812',
  yada: { type: 'yada', id: 'nkfsh000136' },
  audit: {
    created_at: '2022-10-03T09:09:22.672144670Z'
  },
  type: 'yada',
  payload: {
    encounter: {
      provider: {
        first_name: 'yada',
        last_name: 'Doublecheck',
        npi: '1366553539'
      },
      appointment: {
        scheduled: '2022-10-03T09:04:10.588Z',
        start: '2022-09-19T15:04:05Z',
        end: '2022-09-19T15:14:03Z',
        duration: '955'
      },
      codes: { icd10: [ 'R21' ] },
      pharmacy: 'HEB Pharmacy yada #77 (001)'
    }
  },
  vendor: 'yada'
}
```

Comment: Is `created_at` a real datetime type or is it a string?

Comment: Its a string. I'm trying to do this in mongo shell

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `created_at` field of all documents in your collection by adding one millisecond to it using the $inc and `$toDate` operators in an update query. Here's an example code snippet using `pymongo`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Connect to the MongoDB server
client = MongoClient()

# Select the database and collection
db = client['your_database_name']
collection = db['your_collection_name']

# Define the update query
update_query = { '$inc': { 'audit.created_at': timedelta(milliseconds=1) } }

# Update all documents in the collection
collection.update_many({}, update_query)
```

Comment: thanks, you wouldn't happen to know the mongoshell syntax would you?  EDIT actually that might be enough, thanks

Comment: actually the timedelta part is throwing me off. Do you know the equivilent for mongoshell syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do it is using `$dateAdd`.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "audit.created_at": {
        "$dateAdd": {
          "startDate": {
            $toDate: "$audit.created_at"
          },
          "unit": "millisecond",
          "amount": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vFmAHh0cBMF)

Comment: I get error: MongoServerError: Retryable writes are not supported

Comment: @w_savage never mind. $dateAdd is not supported yet in your 4.0.0 MongoDB

Comment: Shoot. Thanks for trying though. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)  The author is on v4.0.0 which supports neither `$update` pipelines nor `$toDate`.  Assuming performance and/or transactionality is not a huge concern, this can be done on the client side:

```js
db.foo.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var q = new ISODate(doc['audit']['created_at']);
    q.setMilliseconds(1 + q.getMilliseconds())
    rc = db.foo.updateOne({_id:doc['_id']}, {$set: {'audit.created_at':q.toISOStr\
ing()}});
});
```

It is always *highly* recommended that you store dates as real datetime types.

Comment: I get an error with that: MongoServerError: Wrong type for parameter u

Comment: Hmmm...   What version of mongodb server?  Run `db.serverBuildInfo().version`

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0

Comment: Ah.   Pipelines in the `$update` command were introduced in v4.2.   v4.0 is almost 4.5 years old; I'd recommend upgrading if at all possible.

Comment: yeah that would required a lot of red tape to go through

Comment: Edited with a possible client-side solution.